# React Native Elements Image (uri from the web) goes blank. BUG?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-elements

I am using Expo and I have a FlatList of images in my app. When I scroll down, the already **loaded** images from the top of the list go blank...

This is the code of my FlatList component:

```
 <FlatList
    data={images}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
    style={styles.container}
    initialNumToRender={7}
    maxToRenderPerBatch={10}
    windowSize={21} //default value
    removeClippedSubviews
  />
```

And the images I render are basically this:

```
 <Image
     source={{ uri: "https://..." }}
     height={300}
  />
```

I think I am having this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18364

But I am not using an old version of React Native / Expo.

Pd: The Image is from the library "react-native-elements" but having the same problem with the Standard Image component from "react-native".

### My environment

1. Expo: SDK 36 version 3.11.7
2. React-native-cli: 2.0.1
3. React-native: 0.61.4
4. React-native-elements: ^2.0.0,

Running on production mode

Comment: Is it happening on Android device? If yes, please specify OS version

Comment: I have the same issue in Samsung Galaxy S8 and iPhone 6